# В каких случаях ставится запятая между двумя прилагательными?

Tags: запятые, прилагательные

В каких случаях следует поставить запятую между двумя прилагательными? Судя по всему, не во всех случаях в текстах встречается такое написание. Например: "Коричневая, кожаная плеть". Чем это объяснимо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Нормативная запись будет выглядеть так: ***плеть кожаная коричневая***.

Это обычная форма **для наименования товара**: неоднородные определения стоят после определяемого слова, но не обособляются, а запятые между ними  не ставятся.

К примеру, такую же структуру  имеют **названия растений** (только там используется прописная буква), например:  *яблоня Китайка золотая ранняя.*

2) А вот запись ***коричневая, кожаная плеть*** в каком-либо тексте вызывает сомнения.

Определения **явно неоднородные** (они выражены относительным и качественным прилагательным), в этом случае запятая между ними не ставится. По правилам иногда возможно **сближение признаков**, но для этих прилагательных **трудно подобрать  общую тему.**

3) Вопрос об общем признаке для сближения значений рассмотрен у Розенталя: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98

**Согласованные определения являются однородными:**
3) если в условиях контекста, характеризуя предмет с разных сторон, объединяются каким-либо **общим признаком** (внешним видом, сходством производимого ими впечатления, отнесением к отдаленному общему понятию, причинно-следственной связью и т. д.): В небе таяло одно маленькое, золотистое облачко (М. Г.) — внешний вид; Наступили тяжёлые, мрачные времена (‘тяжелые, поэтому и мрачные’)